# Errors with find_if() & mem_fun1()

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, stdvector

I have code that worked well in Visual C++ 6.0.  Now I need to get it working in VS 2017.  I have some error messages when I compile, and I'm really not sure how to fix it.  Here's the code:

```
class CTagDB : public CObject
{
    ...
    bool SameTag (const CTagDB *TagDB) { return TagDB && *this == *TagDB; }
    ...
}

class CTagsDB : public CObject
{
    ...
    std::vector<CTagDB*> m_Tags;
    ...
}

bool CTagsDB::IsDup(const CTagDB *TagDB) const
{
    return std::find_if(m_Tags.begin(), m_Tags.end(),
                        std::bind2nd(std::mem_fun1(CTagDB::SameTag),
                        TagDB)) != m_Tags.end();
}
```

For this code I get the following errors:

> error C2039: 'mem_fun1': is not a member of 'std' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\map(16):
>
> note: see declaration of 'std'
>
> error C3867: 'CTagDB::SameTag': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
>
> error C3861: 'mem_fun1': identifier not found
>
> error C2672: 'std::find_if': no matching overloaded function found
>
> error C2780: '_InIt std::find_if(_InIt,_InIt,_Pr)': expects 3 arguments - 2 provided

Seeing the methods begin() & end(), I suspect that there is a problem with the way the vectors are being used, because originally the code was written without iterators.  But this fragment of code is so clever as to be very difficult to decipher, let alone maintain (by me).

Can anyone help me figure out what is going on here and how to fix it?

Comment: Try `std::mem_fun(&CTagDB::SameTag)`. Better still, use a lambda: `std::find_if(m_Tags.begin(), m_Tags.end(), [TagDB](CTagDB* p) { return p->SameTag(TagDB); });`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I would prefer to avoid the use of lambda.  I haven't, yet, seen a basic C++ class where lambda is taught, so I can't count on the next guy being able to decipher it correctly.  If my code is doing something simple, I want it to look simple.  If you put the switch from mem_fun1() to mem_fun() in an answer, I'll give you credit for solving my problem.

Comment: Have you seen a basic C++ class where `std::bind2nd` and `std::mem_fun` are taught? They look much more hairy.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, I agree with you - bind2nd() & mem_fun() are too complicated.  But in the end they are methods with arguments & return values, and they are documented in standard library references.  So anyone who completes a basic C++ course should be able to work that out.  (The hitch in this is that these methods participate in design patterns that are not mentioned in the references & may not be taught in basic C++ courses, so that makes it a challenge.)  Anyway, I would prefer to avoid these complicated & esoteric solutions to what are essentially simple problems.